# And now you see it

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

It tickles me that the word TUNA is found within FORTUNATE.  And there is a COFFIN in SCOFFING.  And who put the LAGER in the VILLAGER?  The SKIER in RISKIER?  The ROMAN in the MICROMANAGER?  The TURBAN in DISTURBANCE?  The ONCE in CONCERN?  The MEAT in PERMEATE?

These words have always been there.  Although I've been looking at them my whole life, I've only just noticed them recently.  They were hidden in plain sight!

Maybe you've noticed them before.  Let's test your powers of observation on some others.

Example:

```
Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 5-letter word to complete all the words:
    P_____G
    ST_____G
    DIS_____G


--------------------------------------


Answer:  ROBIN

because it completes all the words:

    PROBING
    STROBING
    DISROBING
```

See how many of the 10 below you can solve.

Super helpful clue:  The fill-in word is semantically and etymologically unrelated to the containing words.  (Well, almost always.)

```
1.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 4-letter word to complete all the words:
        SI____NES
        MO____NG
        FI____TY


2.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 6-letter word to complete all the words:
        S______
        B______
        CA______


3.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 6-letter word to complete all the words:
        CH______
        REP______
        IMP______T


4.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 5-letter word to complete all the words:
        C_____NG
        G_____NG
        _____T


5.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 4-letter word to complete all the words:
        VI____S
        CHO____S
        WAL____S


6.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 5-letter word to complete all the words:
        _____RD
        _____UNT
        _____VER


7.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 4-letter word to complete all the words:
        ____DS
        L____T
        SE____
        ST____
        S____ESS


8.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 6-letter word to complete all the words:
        EX______G
        INS______G
        RES______G


9.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 6-letter word to complete all the words:
        PU______S
        FLE______S
        FLA______S


And this one is just too icky not to include:

10.  Fill in the blanks below with a well-known 5-letter word to complete all the words:
        BA_____T
        EA_____T
        HOR_____
```

NOTE:  Problem #2 relies on an obscure word which is often mistaken for a more common word.  I am disqualifying it and removing it from consideration.  However, you may still try to solve it, if you like.

---

**Epilogue:**

@Randal'Thor and @El-Guest — That was some quick solving!  Good work.

Here are more fun facts about these words:

> 1.  DELI is also contained in YODELING, DANDELION, and CHANDELIER
>
>
>   5.  RUSE is also contained in UTERUSES and ABSTRUSE
>
>
>   7.  AMEN is also contained in ORNAMENT
>
>
>   10.  Also AMUSEMENT and CASEMENT

Now be sure to check out the B side [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83737/and-now-you-see-it-ii-the-b-side).

Comment: [Obligatory Simpsons reference](https://media.giphy.com/media/3orieTbpizSEqu1DZ6/giphy.gif)

Comment: NOTE:  #2 relies on an obscure word which is often mistaken for a more common word.  I am disqualifying it and removing it from consideration.  However, you may still try to solve it, if you like.

Comment: Awww, just saw your comment after I (maybe?) got it.

Comment: Fun puzzle, @SlowMagic!

Comment: @Randal'Thor — The fact that it was disqualified as being too difficult, and yet you solved it anyway, earns you far more in respect, honor, and reverence.  The anecdote about John von Neumann and the very difficult problem comes to mind.  (He was presented with an extremely difficult problem that can be solved fairly easily with a trick.  He solved it almost instantly.  When the others said, "Oh, you must know about the trick..."  He replied, "What trick?"    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312840/infinite-series-anecdote-about-john-von-neumann?noredirect=1)

Comment: Nice ham you've got here! It would be a shame if someone put s and e on the sides of it!

Comment: @El-Guest [THE Simpsons reference](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT5LMwQqgAXNsAezuw/giphy.gif)

Comment: "*List of words containing "meow": meow, meowed, meowing, meows, homeowner*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. From me

   > DELI (sidelines, modeling, fidelity)
2. From me and Rand al’ Thor, somewhat simultaneously

   > LENDER (slender, blender, calender)
3. From me

   > AIRMEN (chairmen, repairmen, impairment)
4. From Rand al’ Thor

   > RABBI (crabbing, grabbing, rabbit)
5. From Gareth McCaughan

   > RUSE (viruses, choruses, walruses)
6. From me

   > DISCO (discord, discount, discover)
7. From me

   > AMEN (amens, lament, seamen, stamen, sameness)
8. From Rand al’ Thor

   > PECTIN (expecting, inspecting, respecting)
9. From Rand al’ Thor

   > SHINES (pushiness, flashiness, fleshiness)
10. From me

    > SEMEN (basement, easement, horsemen)

Comment: Between us we have all except #2 now ...

Comment: Nice!! Great answers so far (although 2 looks the hardest @Randal'Thor haha)

Comment: Given the OP's latest comment, I think mine fits better than yours for #2 :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor LOL just found it!

Comment: I suspect rot13(ehfr) is actually intended for #5.

Comment: That works tons better — thanks, @GarethMcCaughan!

Comment: For #5, please keep the two solutions, as the previous one was fitting too.

Comment: @Cœur I’d argue that chokings and walkings are not actually words.

Comment: @El-Guest https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chokings and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walkings

Answer (score 13):

El-Guest already [solved](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83692/5373) #1, #3, #5, #6, #7, #10. The remaining solutions are:

2.

> LENDER (slender, blender, calender). Either the OP misspelled "calendar", or we're allowed to use [rather obscure words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calender). Or there's a better answer.

4.

> RABBI (crabbing, grabbing, rabbit).

8.

> PECTIN (expecting, inspecting, respecting).

9.

> SHINES (pushiness, fleshiness, flashiness).

Comment: Nice teamwork! :)